# express app settings stored in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Currently I set my express app settings in app.js like so:

```
app.set('siteCategoryNo', '900');
app.set('brandCompanyName', 'Website Name');
app.set('brandDomainName', 'website.com');
```

Instead I would like to store them in a separate file **app-config.js** like so:

```
/*  
 * app-config.js
 */
module.exports = function () {

    var appSettings = {

        settings: [{
            key: 'siteCategoryNo',
             val: '900'
        }, {
            key: 'brandCompanyName',
            val: 'website name'
        }, {
            key: 'brandDomainName',
            val: 'website.com'
        }]

        // all other settings omitted

    }

    return appSettings;

};
```

This is what **app.js** would look like:

```
// all other code omitted
var configSettings = require('./app-config.js')();

for (var i = 0; i <= configSettings.settings.length; i++) {
    var applicationSettings = configSettings.settings.pop();
    app.set(applicationSettings.key, applicationSettings.val);
}
```

I'm doing things this way because I am building a nearly identical website with another developer, but we have some different settings and routes. We're hoping this will make merging easier.

The loop over the associative array (if that's what you call it) works only when the object array is in the **app.js** file.  I'd like to separate this into **app-config.js**, but as soon as I do none of my vars are set.

Is this possible?

Comment: It seems you have off-by-one error in a `for` loop. It should be strict `<` sign in the loop condition.

Comment: Thanks @Thevs I've since replaced it with the forEach loop that MinusFour proposed below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {

    var appSettings = {

        settings: [{
            key: 'siteCategoryNo',
             val: '900'
        }, {
            key: 'brandCompanyName',
            val: 'website name'
        }, {
            key: 'brandDomainName',
            val: 'website.com'
        }]

        // all other settings omitted

    }

    appSettings.settings.forEach(function(setting){
      app.set(setting.key, setting.val);
      });
    return app;
};
```

And then from `app.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = require('configFile')(express());
```

Comment: I like this solution but is there a reason to specify a key for `key` and a key for `value`?

Comment: It's `key` for the setting key and `val` for the setting value. It fits the [`app.set(key, val)`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set) function signature.